# Get rid of miniframes from first and last slides

Tags: beamer, mini-frames

Basically, I need to get rid of the miniframe (where the sections go) in the first slide and the last slide, is that possible? Here my MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]
    \setbeamercovered{invisible}
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\useoutertheme[footline=empty,subsection=false]{miniframes}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{The Simpsons}
\author{Krusty the Clown\\(this first slide must not have the miniframes!!)}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

% Main slide
\begin{frame}
   \titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{Second slide, yeah!!}
\begin{frame}
    This slide must have the miniframe, the first one must not!
\end{frame}

\section{Third slide, yeah!!}
\begin{frame}
    This slide must also have the miniframe (and so forth), the first one must not!
\end{frame}

% Last slide
\begin{frame}
    Thank you for your attention\\(this slide must not have the miniframes!!)
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Thanks for any hints,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

found it, simply use [plain] in each slide/frame environment:

```
...
% Main slide
\begin{frame}[plain]
   \titlepage
\end{frame}
...
...
% Last slide
\begin{frame}[plain]
    Thank you for your attention\\(this slide must not have the miniframes!!)
\end{frame}
```